# Synopsys: Repeated compiles produce different results. How to automate iterated compile?

Tags: optimization, area, synthesis

I'm new to using Design Compiler.  In the past, I've done mostly FPGA work.  Right now, I'm using Synopsys to determine the minimum are necessary to represent some circuits (using the Nangate 45nm library).  I'm not doing P&R right now; I'm just trying to determine transistor area.

My only optimization constraint is to minimize area.  I've noticed that if I tell DC to compile more than one time in a row, it produces different (and usually smaller) results each time.

- I've looked and looked and failed to see if this is mentioned in a manual or anywhere in any discussion.  Is it meant to work this way?
- This suggests that optimization is stopping earlier than it could, so it's not REALLY minimizing area.  Any idea why?
- Is there a way I can tell it to increase the effort and/or tell it to automatically iterate compiles so that it will converge on the smallest design?

I'm *guessing* that DC is expecting to meet timing constraints, but I've given it a purely combinatorial block and no timing constraint.  Did they never consider the usage scenario when all you want to do is work out the minimum gate area for a combinatorial circuit?

Comment: I've figured out how to do iteration.  The scripting is done in Tcl, so it was easy to loop.  But one of my colleagues (who is only familiar with Cadence tools) says that there should be a way to tell it to spend more time on optimization (besides setting the effort level).

Answer (score 1):

On a pure combinatorial circuit you can use a set_max_delay constraint and DC will attempt to meet that.

For reduced area you can use -map_effort high or -map_effort ultra to get it to work harder.

DC is a funny beast, and the algorithms it uses change as processes advance and make certain activities more or less useful.  A lot of pre-layout optimization is less useful since the whole situation can change once the gates are actually placed and routed.

Comment: The command I'm using is `compile_ultra -area_high_effort_script`, which does a better job than compile, but it still requires many passes to reach a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I filed a support ticket with Synopsys.  I was using a 2010 version of design compiler.  Apparently, area optimization has been improved since then, and the 2014 version will minimize area in one compiler pass.